# Firebase FCM on TypeScript: "The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement FCM for my App, and I couldn't yet receive the device token due to this error. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
export const requestFirebaseNotificationPermission = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    messaging
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => messaging.getToken())
      .then((firebaseToken) => {
        resolve(firebaseToken);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
```

It seems there might be an issue with th ServiceWorker:

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
```

I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) document which seems to touch this subject, but I confess I didn't understand what needs to be done. Should I create a file named firebase-messaging-sw.js and make it available on my routes? How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found an article more well explained about this topic [here](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/adicionando-push-notifications-a-um-web-app-com-firebase-2a20cf12b6fe), and could enable notifications in my React app following these steps.

As I'm new to this, it was not clear for me that the firebase-messaging-sw.js file should be placed in the "public" directory.