# Getting The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). while getting FCM token from react js frontend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up FCM for push notifications, I have been following the tutorial in FCM documentation however I am getting 2 errors

Error1: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Error 2:

```
registerDefaultSw.ts:43 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43:1)
    at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28:1)
    at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43:1)
```

So far this is what I have done:
I have created a firebaseInit.js in my root directory

This is the code of firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //using firebase version 9.12.1
import 'firebase/compat/messaging';
import {getMessaging, getToken, onMessage} from 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Myconfigs here
  };

const app=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);
messaging.getToken({vapidKey: "myvapidkeyhere"});


export const fetchtoken=(setTokenFound, setFCMtoken)=>{
 return getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'myvapidkeyhere' }).then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
        setTokenFound(true);
        setFCMtoken(currentToken);
        console.log('currentToken', currentToken);
    } else {
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      setTokenFound(false);
      setFCMtoken('');
      
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // ...
  });
}
    




export const requestPermission=()=> {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
         return getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'BJ6svnWkMddFqduSsw57xRPf6MNeS_hNGpfTUQNKvcqc04AtvLAaMSg-vpY3zj6q1ZTXu-wak2AXWUQeiDMHRGo' }).then((currentToken) => {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log('currentToken', currentToken);
            } else {
                console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
        })
   
        
        
      }
    //     )
    // }  
      else{
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
      }
    });
    }


export const requestFirebaseNotificationPermission = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    messaging
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => messaging.getToken())
      .then((firebaseToken) => {

        resolve(firebaseToken);
        console.log(firebaseToken);
        console.log("messaging permission granted ")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });

export const onMessageListener = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });
```

After that in my firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
const config = {
    "my configs here"
};

app=firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);



messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  console.log(event)
  return event;
});
```

and then I called these 2 functions in my app.js

```
render() {
    const Layout = this.getLayout();
  requestFirebaseNotificationPermission()
  .then((firebaseToken) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(firebaseToken);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return err;
  });

  
  requestPermission()


    return (
      <React.Fragment>
```

Can someone pls point out what I am doing wrong

There was already a serviceWorker file in my project I tried modifying it by adding the link to firebase-messaging-sw.js but that didnt work either.

I also tried to modify my index.js and removed the serviceWorker.unregister() and add a new function for registration but that didnt resolve the issue either

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker"
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import "./i18n"

import { Provider } from "react-redux"

import store from "./store"

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"))
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate on behalf of [Yuji Bry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20447561): Does this answer your question? [Firebase FCM on TypeScript: "The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391597/firebase-fcm-on-typescript-the-script-has-an-unsupported-mime-type-text-html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413375/20447561). Make sure that `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is in the public directory.